# Counting the number of dots in a string

Tags: bash

How do I count the number of dots in a string in BASH? For example

```
VAR="s454-da4_sd.fs_84-df.f-sds.a_as_d.a-565sd.dasd"

# Variable VAR contains 5 dots
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [count occurrences of char in string using bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16679369/count-occurrences-of-char-in-string-using-bash)

Answer (score 18):

You can do it combining `grep` and `wc` commands:

```
echo "string.with.dots." | grep -o "\." | wc -l
```

Explanation:

```
grep -o   # will return only matching symbols line/by/line
wc -l     # will count number of lines produced by grep
```

Or you can use only `grep` for that purpose:

```
echo "string.with.dots." | grep -o "\." | grep -c "\."
```

Answer (score 8):

`awk` alternative:

```
echo "$VAR" | awk -F. '{ print NF - 1 }'
```

Output:

```
5
```

Answer (score 7):

```
VAR="s454-da4_sd.fs_84-df.f-sds.a_as_d.a-565sd.dasd"
echo $VAR | tr -d -c '.' | wc -c
```

tr `-d` deletes given characters from the input. `-c` takes the inverse of given characters. together, this expression deletes non '.' characters and counts the resulting length using `wc`.

Answer (score 6):

Solution in pure `bash` :

```
VAR="s454-da4_sd.fs_84-df.f-sds.a_as_d.a-565sd.dasd" 
VAR_TMP="${VAR//\.}" ; echo $((${#VAR} - ${#VAR_TMP}))
```

or even just as chepner mentioned:

```
VAR="s454-da4_sd.fs_84-df.f-sds.a_as_d.a-565sd.dasd" 
VAR_TMP="${VAR//[^.]}" ; echo ${#VAR_TMP}
```

Comment: Or `DOTS=${VAR_TMP//[^.]}; echo ${#DOTS}`.

Answer (score 2):

Temporarily setting `IFS`, pure Bash, no sub-processes:

```
IFS=. VARTMP=(X${VAR}X) # avoid stripping dots
echo $(( ${#VARTMP[@]} - 1 ))
```

Output:

```
5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
VAR="s454-da4_sd.fs_84-df.f-sds.a_as_d.a-565sd.dasd"
dot_count=$( IFS=.; set $VAR; echo $(( $# - 1 )) )
```

This works by setting the field separator to "." in a subshell and setting the positional parameters by word-splitting the string. With N dots, there will be N+1 positional parameters. We finish by subtracting one from the number of positional parameters in the subshell and echoing that to be captured in `dot_count`.

Comment: This will strip leading and trailing dots.