# Count occurrences of a char in a string using Bash

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I need to count the *number of occurrences of a char in a string* using Bash.

In the following example, when the char is (for example) `t`, it *`echo`s* the correct number of occurrences of `t` in `var`, but when the character is comma or semicolon, it prints out zero:

```
var = "text,text,text,text" 
num = `expr match $var [,]`
echo "$num"
```

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18736/how-to-count-the-number-of-a-specific-character-in-each-line

Answer (score 130, accepted):

I would use the following `awk` command:

```
string="text,text,text,text"
char=","
awk -F"${char}" '{print NF-1}' <<< "${string}"
```

I'm splitting the string by `$char` and print the number of resulting fields minus 1.

If your shell does not support the `<<<` operator, use `echo`:

```
echo "${string}" | awk -F"${char}" '{print NF-1}'
```

Comment: what if var is a file with text. how can the above be altered for this?

Comment: @HattrickNZ Then use: `$(grep -o "$needle" < filename | wc -l)`

Comment: @hek2mgi. but this one outputs 3 ?! when I am echo "number_of_occurences"

Comment: @Amir What do you expect?

Comment: You can skip the `wc -l`, just use `grep -c`, it works on both bsd grep and linux grep.

Comment: @andsens `grep -c` will only output the number of matching lines. It does not count multiple matches per line.

Comment: I want to count '$'s in a string, how can I escape '$' from main string?

Comment: this would mis-count when passing through a blank line embedded within the larger input file (shall that be the case). A blank line yields NF = 0, so it'll end up printing a negative 1 instead .

Comment: The solution works as long as there are no line breaks in the text

Answer (score 177):

you can for example remove all other chars and count the whats remains, like:

```
var="text,text,text,text"
res="${var//[^,]}"
echo "$res"
echo "${#res}"
```

will print

```
,,,
3
```

or

```
tr -dc ',' <<<"$var" | awk '{ print length; }'
```

or

```
tr -dc ',' <<<"$var" | wc -c    #works, but i don't like wc.. ;)
```

or

```
awk -F, '{print NF-1}' <<<"$var"
```

or

```
grep -o ',' <<<"$var" | grep -c .
```

or

```
perl -nle 'print s/,//g' <<<"$var"
```

Comment: [some more trick here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-appleosx-bsd-bash-count-characters-variables/) like `y="${x//[^s|S]}"; echo "${#y}"`

Comment: use the first one, should always avoid resorting to spawning another process to do work like this, it can severely impact performance when using with large iteration loops. As a rule external process execution should be a last resort when using iterating or repeating operations.

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功包卓轩because for example `echo -n some line | wc -l`

Comment: Code block 4 is the best in my opinion. We need to make it easier to get to: `tr -dc ',' <<<"$var" | wc -c`

Comment: @bgStack15 code block 1 does not initial additional process, and maybe has better performance if you have huge number of line to parsing.

Comment: Just FYI, `tr -dc ',' <<<"$var" | awk '{ print length; }'` seems to be way faster than the first option.

Comment: Note that `sed 's/[^,]//g'` is much faster then using `${var//[^,]}`. So for example checking number of options would be much faster this way: `echo $allDomains | sed 's/[^-]//g' | wc -c`

Comment: after taking [benchmark](https://transang.me/performance-benchmark-count-number-of-occurrences-of-a-character/), I got the methods list after sorted from fastest to slowest: *variable expansion* > *tr* > *grep* > *awk* > *perl*

Comment: @transang your "benchmark" benchmarking nothing. Reading a text file line by line and executing the commands zilion times, and summing the counts in shell is an example of the worst programming practices. Of course, the results are absolutely pointless. If want count commas in some file, you should NOT to do it line-by-line.

Comment: @jm666 you are correct on advising be not to read file line by line. I also figured out that the reason of my code slow speed is the line-by-line-reading behavior. However, in my benchmark, I also do the only-read experiment, it shows the reading time. You can subtract this reading time from all others to get processing time

Comment: @transang Need subtracting not only the reading time, but (and most important) the command start time too. (aka: fork-exec). For example. `perl` start time is much bigger as for example the `tr`. Therefore you got the result as the perl is worst. But if you using the correct approach, you need start perl only **once** and the results will be very different. The same applies for example for `awk` too. Be fair, and just tell in your web-page the truth. Or develop a code, where the WHOLE FILE is processed by one fork-exec cycle and you can safely publishing the results. Not in the current case.

Comment: you are right. not only file open/close but the startup time of the program is also an important factor. at least, when startup time is similar to processing time, my benchmark result is useful. Let me point it out in my post

Comment: this solution is **very** slow if you the string you are processing is very large.

Comment: @MatthewSnyder Which one do you mean by "this" of the listed 7 different methods? And how large is the "very large"?

Comment: Why do you not like wc?

Comment: @Robert becase the `wc` incorrectly counts the number of lines, in the input. Of course, the `wc -c` is OK but because of the line counting problem I don't like it. example, the: `printf "line1\nline2\n" | wc -l` prints `2` but the `printf "line1\nline2" | wc -l` prints only `1`.

Comment: Noob question - does the `<<<"$var"` piece do a similar job to `<(echo "$var")`, just without the overhead of spawning new `echo` process? I don't see the `<<<` in the wild internets very often...

Answer (score 113):

You can do it by combining `tr` and `wc` commands.  For example, to count `e` in the string  `referee`

```
echo "referee" | tr -cd 'e' | wc -c
```

output

```
4
```

Explanations: Command `tr -cd 'e'` removes all characters other than 'e', and Command `wc -c` counts the remaining characters.

Multiple lines of input are also good for this solution, like command `cat mytext.txt | tr -cd 'e' | wc -c` can counts `e` in the file `mytext.txt`, even thought the file may contain many lines.

*** Update ***

To solve the multiple spaces in from of the number (@tom10271), simply append a piped tr command:

```
 tr -d ' '
```

For example:

```
echo "referee" | tr -cd 'e' | wc -c | tr -d ' '
```

Comment: In macOS, output contains mulitple spaces in front of the number

Comment: Great, many thanks for the `tr`, it really sounds to be a great tool i didn't know about. Today i learned something new!

Answer (score 16):

awk is very cool, but why not keep it simple?

```
num=$(echo $var | grep -o "," | wc -l)
```

You could then re-use it as a function:

```
# usage: echo "1,2,3,4,5" | text.count # outputs 4
function text.count(){
    grep -o "$1" | wc -l
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Building on everyone's great answers and comments, this is the shortest and sweetest version:

`grep -o "$needle" <<< "$haystack" | wc -l`

Answer (score 2):

awk works well if you your server has it

```
var="text,text,text,text" 
num=$(echo "${var}" | awk -F, '{print NF-1}')
echo "${num}"
```

Comment: Just as a note: `awk -F,` looks for a `,`. You can do the following: `awk -F"${your_char}"`

Answer (score 2):

also check this out, for example we wanna count `t`

```
echo "test" | awk -v RS='t' 'END{print NR-1}'
```

or in `python`

```
python -c 'print "this is for test".count("t")'
```

or even better, we can make our script dynamic with `awk`

```
echo 'test' | awk '{for (i=1 ; i<=NF ; i++) array[$i]++ } END{ for (char in array) print char,array[char]}' FS=""
```

in this case output is like this :

```
e 1
s 1
t 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I Would suggest the following:

```
var="any given string"
N=${#var}
G=${var//g/}
G=${#G}
(( G = N - G ))
echo "$G"
```

No call to any other program

Answer (score 0):

The `awk` solutions provided here so far all break if there's a line break in your text. E.g.:

```
text="one,two,thr
ee,four"
DELIM=','
count=$( awk -F"$DELIM" '{print NF-1}' <<<"${text}" )
echo $count
```

Result:

```
2
1
```

The solution that will also work correctly with line breaks is:

```
text="one,two,thr
ee,four"
DELIM=','
count=$( awk 'BEGIN{RS="'"$DELIM"'";FS=""}END{print NR-1}' <<<"${text}" )
echo $count
```

Result is `3`.

Answer (score 0):

## Count fixed strings (-F) from a file

export searchpattern=$(echo ",")

echo "text,text,text,text" | tr "," '\n' | sed 's/$/,/g' > filename

export count=$(grep -F $searchpattern filename | wc -l)

echo "$count-1" | bc