# remove URL's of a certain length

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed

I have a flat file with a list of URL's I want to spider. I only want to check the ones of a certain length though. I am unaware of any way to cut the shorter urls from the list via bash. Would it be possible to create a simple for do loop to remove lines in the file that contain less than 5 forward slashed? "/"

Comment: Use `grep` to select all lines not matching a patterm with at least 5 slashes.

Comment: You can use this to count your `/`s in bash: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16679640/1716866.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply to:

```
grep '://.*/.*/.*/.*/.*/' urls.txt
```

This will only match lines that have at least 5 slashes.

Comment: No problem, glad to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
grep '//.*/.*/.*/' filename
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.