# count the number of items in a shell variable

Tags: shell

I have a shell variable sampleDir:

```
sampleDir=/home/sample*
echo $sampleDir
```

will give:

```
/home/sample_001 /home/sample_002 /home/sample_003
```

(note there are sub-directories under the sample_*** ones)

If I would like to count how much of these items are in this $sampleDir variable, what would be a best way please? (Expect to return 3)

Comment: I'm not sure that I believe the output given the setup. Where is the `/subdir` portion coming from?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Sorry just saw your comment. I have edited the post. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Store the variables in an array:

```
sampleDir=(/home/sample*)
```

Use Parameter Expansion to get count of items in array:

```
echo "${#sampleDir[@]}"
```

Answer (score 3):

`sampleDir=/home/sample*` assigns a literal `'/home/sample*'` into `sampleDir`

```
$ echo "$sampleDir" 
/home/sample*
```

but if you don't double-quote the variable expansion, it will undergo glob expansion (unless `set -f` is on)
and splitting on `$IFS` characters (characters in the `IFS` variable— normally space, tab, and newline).

You can count the number of items after the expansion by passing the unquoted `$sampleDir` to a function that
counts its arguments.

```
argc() { argc=$#; } 
argc $sampleDir
echo $argc      #will print the number of items $sampleDir expanded to
```

This would be how you can do it portably, on any POSIX shell (solutions based on things like arrays are limited to shells that have them).

---

( I recommend returning stuff from shell functions by assigning it to a global variable of the same name as the function.
It's portable, namespace-clean, and very fast (unlike echoing and then using captures to get the echoed string, which is common, but rather expensive))

Comment: Thanks so much for the thorough explanation! So many things to learn in shell:)

Answer (score 2):

As posed, you are trying to count the number of spaces in your string and add one. There are [a number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16679369/2988730) of good ways of doing this. The shortest to type is probably something along the lines of

```
COUNT=$(grep -o ' ' <<< "$sampleDir" | wc -l)
((COUNT++))
```

The problem with this approach is that you can not have spaces anywhere in the file names. A better way might be to just store the name of the directory you are interested in and run a command like `find` on that:

```
sampleRoot=/home
find "$sampleRoot" -name 'sample*' | wc -l
```

Comment: Very useful. I actually wondered if there was a wc -l approach:)

Comment: Sorry the comment was meant for the https://stackoverflow.com/a/44934368/10907864 which I have already upvoted.