# Counting multiple characters in text file using wc -

Tags: bash, word-count

I have a given file text below:

```
aatgcacatgttgcatatcaagtggatatgggtggtggaaaactgtataatggccaagcc
aatttccgtttattatttgacccaactcaagcagtagctattccgagtagcgaatttcca
```

I am trying to find a `grep` and word count `wc` command that allows me to find and then count all the "a" and "g" in the file text.

I have previously tried using

```
egrep 'a|g' outputSequence.txt|wc -c
```

I am using `'a|g'` from: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37313/how-do-i-grep-for-multiple-patterns-with-pattern-having-a-pipe-character

I have tried using:

```
grep -o 'a|g' outputSequence.txt|wc -l
```

The code:

```
grep -o 'a|g' outputSequence.txt|wc -l
```

outputs 0.

I cannot find a resource that allows me to grep and word count both a and g in each line.

Comment: Are you trying to solve the problem using any method or do you need to use grep and wc? Your task might be easier to solve using awk such as discussed in this [Count Occurrences of char in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16679369/count-occurrences-of-a-char-in-a-string-using-bash) SO thread.

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is ok and needs to be improved:

- `grep -o 'a|g'` searches for `a` followed by `|` followed by `g`. You need to escape `|` to make it an OR. The `grep -o 'a\|g'` will search for `a` letter OR letter `g`  in the output. It will output `a` and `g` characters separated by newlines.
- Then use `sort | uniq -c` to sort the letters and print the count.
- Don't use `egrep`, it's deprecated. Use `grep -E` instead.

The command:

```
grep -o 'a\|g' outputSequence.txt | sort | uniq -c
```

should output:

```
 36 a
 26 g
```

But maybe you want the sum of count of `a`s and `g`s, then you were close enough:

```
grep -o 'a\|g' outputSequence.txt | wc -l
```

Comment: Character classes would do the job nicely: `grep -o '[actg]' | sort | uniq -c` to get count of each DNA bases occurrences, or `grep -o '[ag]' | sort | uniq -c` to count only `a` and `g`.

Comment: There's also `grep -o -e a -e g | wc -l`.