# How to print submodules levels/depth

Tags: git

I got a project with multiple submodules, I want to list for each submodule it depth relatively
The project:

```
main_project
    submodule1
    submodule1\submodule1_1
    submodule1\submodule2_1\submodule2_1_1
    submodule2\submodule2_1\submodule2_1_1\submodule2_1_1_1\
    submodule3
```

The output I want to get:

```
submodule1 - level 0
submodule1\submodule1_1 - level 1
submodule1\submodule2_1\submodule2_1_1 - level 2
submodule2\submodule2_1\submodule2_1_1\submodule2_1_1_1\ - level 3
submodule3 - level 0
```

Comment: tried to count "/" as relative position to the main project
git submodule foreach --recursive "pwd | wc -c'/'"
But it doesn't work....

Comment: Are you looking for : [Count occurrences of a char in a string using Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16679369/count-occurrences-of-a-char-in-a-string-using-bash) ?

Comment: @LeGEC tried it as an option
git submodule foreach --recursive "awk -F"${char}" '{print NF}' <<< pwd"
But seems something went wrong

Comment: that's a one liner. Have you tried writing it in two lines ? :)

Comment: You are having issues with escaping the script you are passing inside the `"..."` argument to `git submodule foreach ...`. You can solve the escaping problems by writing your command in a file (e.g `/tmp/count.sh`) and call `git submodule ...  /tmp/count.sh`.

Comment: an answer like @phd's looks more robust, though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git submodule foreach -q --recursive git rev-parse --git-dir |
    awk '{split($0, a, "/modules/", s); print $0, "- Level", length(s)-1}'
```

Explanation:

```
git submodule foreach -q --recursive
```

Run a command on all submodules recursive.

```
git rev-parse --git-dir
```

Run this command for every submodule — show the path to its `.git/modules` directory. Example:

```
$ git submodule foreach -q --recursive git rev-parse --git-dir

$root/.git/modules/mod1
$root/.git/modules/mod2
$root/.git/modules/mod3
$root/.git/modules/mod3/modules/subdir/submodule
```

All modules in the example are level 0 modules, the last one is level 1. Counting slashes wouldn't help as there are subdirectories (a subsubmodule buried deeper than the root of a submodule). Let's count `/modules/` with `awk`:

```
awk '{split($0, a, "/modules/", s); print $0, "- Level", length(s)-1}'
```

Every input line is split by `/modules/` and the list of separators is put into the array `s`. Then we just count the number of `/modules/` and nicely print the result:

```
git submodule foreach -q --recursive git rev-parse --git-dir |
    awk '{split($0, a, "/modules/", s); print $0, "- Level", length(s)-1}'

$root/.git/modules/mod1 - Level 0
$root/.git/modules/mod2 - Level 0
$root/.git/modules/mod3 - Level 0
$root/.git/modules/mod3/modules/subdir/submodule - Level 1
```

Print submodules workdirs:

```
$ git submodule foreach -q --recursive 'pwd; git rev-parse --git-dir' |
    awk 'NR%2==1 {submodule=$0} NR%2==0 {split($0, a, "/modules/", s); print submodule, "- Level", length(s)-1}':

$root/mod1 - Level 0
$root/third-party/mod2 - Level 0
$root/third-party/mod3 - Level 0
$root/third-party/mod3/subdir/submodule - Level 1
```